# Debugging Error on Windows 7 and IIS7 with .net 2003

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a windows 7 machine and running .net VS2003.  When I try to run an web app project with debugging on, I get an error "Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugger on the web server."

I have tried many things from the suggestions all over the internet with no success. 
Can someone please advise?

Comment: can you post your debugging settings in config file?

Comment: Thanks Nexus I have resolve issue myself.

Comment: Good News! what was the issue? :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the DefaultAppPool to the Framework 1.1
2. Assign DefaultAppPool to your Application